# OpenVPN on Android TCP retransmissions after OpenVPN server reboot

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, android

I raised OpenVPN on server for the first time. It worked fine until the server rebooted. The firewall configuration is unchanged. When I tcpdump from tun interface on the server, I always get TCP retransmissions on all TCP packets larger than a few bytes in Android.

Using a similar(read: same) configuration on my Linux box from where I'm posting this message now works just fine; no retransmissions, no loss.

It did work just fine before the server rebooted. What could possibly cause this? I already tried rebooting Android, it didn't help.

Client configuration, used on both Linux PC and Android tablet:

```
dev tun
client
remote 192.168.0.1
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
pkcs12 user.p12
mssfix 1480
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
```

1480 is below the mtu of uplink connection on server which is 1492.

I tried adding tun-mtu 1480 to Android but that didn't help either.

Comment: final attempt: i set both 'tun-mtu' and 'mssfix' to **1380** on both server and client. surprisingly, it worked. SOLVED.

Comment: Please answer your question to preserve the solution for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final attempt: i set both 'tun-mtu' and 'mssfix' to **1380** on both server and client. surprisingly, it worked.